# Can I compare coefficient values from different models?

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, weights

I'm modeling conversions with a logistic regression. Each conversion can have up to 3 events (page visit, fill questionnaire, and call). I have 3 domains let's call them A,B, and C.

Rather than using the domain as a model variable, I want to create 3 models

```
modelA<-glm(conv~visit+quest+call, family=binomial,data=Adata)
modelB<-glm(conv~visit+quest+call, family=binomial,data=Bdata)
modelC<-glm(conv~visit+quest+call, family=binomial,data=Cdata)
```

By comparing the models like this, I'm hoping I can draw insights such as "visits in A were more important than visits in C". i.e.

Basically compare the coefficients of visit/quest/call across the different models.

Is this sound analysis?

Comment: Are you comparing weights or parameter values? I don't see any weighting in your models. And why do you = want to model all domains separately?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the regression coefficients. The idea is to compare site A's individual events. I'm afraid if I add site as am input and use a single regression, I won't know stuff like are visits in more persuasive than visits in site B?

Comment: What you are describing is an interaction between site and visit, which you can specify in your model. But to answer your question: yes, you *can* fit and compare separate models. I would suggest that you first decide on the exact model you are trying to estimate (which might involve learning more about interactions and GLMs more generally) before proceeding, though.

Comment: Thanks, can you point out where you think I'm falling short? Don't have to get in detail, just want to know what makes you uncomfortable with the logic.

Comment: Not especially uncomfortable; what you describe is fine. But I don't know the details of your analysis, so it's hard to judge. These questions suggest to me that a bit more preparation/reading would be helpful - but this analysis might still be fine at the end.